# How to run unit tests that are outside Angular project

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

How to run unit tests that are outside Angular project?

> Project structure:
>
> - projects/app1
> - projects/app2
> - projects/app3
> - shared (here we have shared code between apps - this is NOT a project defined in angular.json)

I want to run the the tests from the shared folder as part of one of our projects or even independently. I want to avoid creating a separate project in angular.json for the shared code (because it does not make sense)

I have this problem only after the upgrade to version 15:

Since Angular v15 the `require.context` function from `test.ts` configuration file was removed.

I was using require.context to make tests outside Angular project visible to Karma. Now this was removed:

```
const contextGlobal = require.context('../../../folderOutsideProject/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
contextGlobal.keys().map(contextGlobal);
```

I tried creating a symlink between outsideFolder and project folder. It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same workspace structure and after updating from **v14** to **v15** faced the same problem. I solved this problem by having some changes in **angular.json** and **tsconfig.spec.ts** files:
This is the **test** block of my first project in **angular.json** file:

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/admin/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/admin/karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/admin/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/admin/src/assets",
              "projects/admin/src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/admin/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "include": [
              "../../../shared/services/unitTests/**/*.spec.ts"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
```

and this is my **tsconfig.spec.json** file:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../../shared/services/unitTests/**/*.spec.ts",

  ]
}
```

**Note:** I am using my **tsconfig.spec.ts** file which is located inside my first project but my **angular.json** file is located in the root of my workspace.So the key changes that resulted to fix the problem is the paths in **include** of these 2 files.